# Why does the Gmail API return an "invalid to header" error while my API had been working fine for weeks?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, gmail-api

Using the quickstart guide for the Gmail API with Python, I get an 400 error "Invalid to header" when trying to create a draft.

I have been using my little script for a few weeks and it worked perfectly fine to create invoice drafts in bulk, until one day it just stopped working even though I had not modified any code.

This is the error I get:

```
   1 file(s) copied.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "quickstart.py", line 223, in <module>
main()
File "quickstart.py", line 207, in main
create_draft(service, 'me', message_body)
File "quickstart.py", line 134, in create_draft
draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId=user_id, body=message).execute()
File "C:\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\$User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 842, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?alt=json returned "Invalid to header">
```

When I got this error for the first time, I deleted the credentials file and downloaded a new one. But now this solution doesn't seem to work anymore.

Does the credentials.json file expire after some time?

Comment: What's the "to" header you are using in the email and has it changed?  Could you share the relevant sections from quickstart.py?

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error when tried to send email to `"@something2"` (normal email is `something1@something2`, you might miss `"something1"`, e.g your email is invalid)

Error does not happens if you put normal email, so you should validate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but i have fased this httpError 400 recently which i thought would be an authentication or expirated credential/token error.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Invalid To header". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid To header', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalidArgument'}]">
```

While testing my script, it was doing fine until it ran into a... "<" that had snuck and find his place at the beginning of my provider's email in a json file which would then be placed in the code into mimeMessage['to'] = recipient_email.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOl5Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

i got same error[image]
i hope only there is two chances to get this error

1. check email address properly (validate email) there should be some invalid mails
   or mails have spaceing
   eg :`aanu <space> muhammed.c@gmail.com`

so gmail return 400 error and `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json` link like this

2. check authentication delete old pickle file or json file and re create new authentication key

i used this two it works for me